# Scanner Canon Pixma MX521 gets not recognized

Tags: 14.04, drivers, canon, scanner

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. When I run the application "Simple Scan", it does not recognize my scanner, but when I installed the printer, it got recognized. I can also print without any problems. There was no issue like this when I used Fedora 20 with Gnome Shell 3.10.
Thank you for your help!

<sub>(Info: Translated from Spanish - Original message is found in the [revisions](https://askubuntu.com/posts/583317/revisions))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need the Canon drivers installed for the scanner too. After that you should have the ScanGear tool, that can be run with `scangearmp`.

More [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/725412/47206) on a similar issue.